# UICollectionView - Drag Cells outside the UICollectionView to specific UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` with alot of `UICollectionViewCell`s inside it.

Searched alot, but couldn't find anything near this issue.

My goal is to drag one of the Pink squares (`UICollectionViewCell`) to the Gray view (`UIView`).
You can think of it like dragging a folder on your desktop to your trash can except that I dont want the Pink square to be deleted. Or dragging a icon from your dock (it snaps back).

When the pink area hits the gray area it should just go back to its original position and the same when dropping out anywhere else using some kind of easy statement.

Can anyone help me out or redirect me to some references or samples?
Much appreciated, if you would like more info. Let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If i managed to understand you correctly, i did something very similar once before, i found its much better to use a fake image of the cell, instead of the cell itself.

So for example, cell number 2 is starting to be dragged, you immediately call "SetHidden=YES", and draw at the exact same place a fake one with a simple draw method:

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.cell.bounds.size);
    [self.cell.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This one you can move as you like, and when it should go back, you do it the same way.
Hope this helps you..

Comment: Nice thought. 
Maybe that approach will work.
Btw: with iOS7 there is anew UIView method for taking screenshots/snapshot called:

-(UIView *)snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:(BOOL)afterUpdates;

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me in swift 3:

```
class DragAndDropGestureManager: NSObject {
  var originalPosition: CGPoint?
  var draggedView: UIView?
  var viewSize: CGSize?
  var originalZIndex: CGFloat = 0


  @objc func handleDrag(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch recognizer.state {
    case .began:
      if let view = recognizer.view {
        draggedView = view
        originalPosition = view.frame.origin
        viewSize = view.frame.size
        originalZIndex = view.layer.zPosition
        view.layer.zPosition = 1
      }
    case .changed:
      if let view = recognizer.view {
        let currentPosition = recognizer.location(in: view.superview!)
        let newPosition = CGPoint(x: currentPosition.x - (viewSize!.width / 2.0), y: currentPosition.y - (viewSize!.height / 2.0))
        view.frame.origin = newPosition
      } else {
        self.finishDrag()
      }
    case .ended:
      finishDrag()
    default:
      print("drag default \(recognizer.state.rawValue)")
    }
  }

  func finishDrag() {
    self.draggedView?.frame.origin = originalPosition!
    self.draggedView?.layer.zPosition = originalZIndex

    originalZIndex = 0
    originalPosition = nil
    draggedView = nil
  }
}
```

i added a gesture recognizer in the function `public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`
like this:

```
if self.dragManager != nil && cell.gestureRecognizers == nil {
  cell.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: dragManager!, action: #selector(DragAndDropGestureManager.handleDrag)))
}
```

the if, is for not adding gesutre recognition more than once because the cell are being reused

**don't forget to add** `collectioView.clipToBounds = false` **otherwise the dragged cell will be clipped when trying to move out of the collection view's bounds**

Comment: can your share more specific code so I can use your code. Here in your answer I am not able understand what is dragManager!.
My requirement is similar to user023 but slightly change is:
If I drag pink cell to grey cell, pink cell will disappear from collectionView and grey cell will be in second collectionView. I need to perform an action when pink hit to grey. Please help me thanks.

Comment: self.dragManager is the local instance of DragAndDropGestureManager.
@user023 wanted the cell he dragged to go back to its place, so I did.
If you want to detect if a pink cell was dragged and released over a gray square you need to pass the location of the gesture from the '.ended' case to the view controller and check for intersection with the gray square.
Don't forget to convert the location to the same grid of the gray square